# How to add a total from a column in another sheet if it falls between 2 dates

Tags: google-sheets, formulas

I am trying to add a total from a column in another sheet if it falls between 2 dates and it is not working. Any help would be so much appreciated!

Here is what I have:

```
=SUMIFS(’2022’!AB:AB,‘2022’!A:A,‘2022’!A:A,">="&DATE(2022, 1, 1),"<="&DATE(2022, 1, 31))
```

Comment: Keep in mind that we can't see your spreadsheet. We don't know the layout, data, data types or ranges. We don't know your end goal or the scope of your application. The most efficient and effective way to receive help is to provide a link to your spreadsheet (or a copy of it, or a limited but realistic representative sample from it); then hand-enter the results you want a formula to produce, in the range where you want it to appear.

Answer (score 0):

You included the **criterion_range** twice but without putting the relevant criterion between them.

Try specifying: `criterion_range1` followed by `criterion1`, then `criterion_range2` followed by `criterion2`

=SUMIFS(2022!AB:AB,2022!A:A,">="&DATE(2022, 1, 1),2022!A:A,"<="&DATE(2022, 1, 31))